# 'Unable to set property 'actControlType' of undefined or null reference' error

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Using VS2015 with IE9, I've got a modalpopupextender that often misfires.  Sometimes it shows, sometimes it doesn't.  I ran this in Debug mode and this line was highlighted:

```
this._backgroundElement.dataset.actControlType = "MdlCommentsExtender";
```

This isn't something I set, this line appears to be inside the AjaxControlToolkit.  Anyone know how to correct this issue?  I looked at my copy of Ajax and it appears I'm running V16.1

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in [v16.1.1 release](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/releases/tag/16.1.1): https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/17